# How to convert dataframe column with datetime value to ISO-8601 time format with timezone?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, strptime

**How can I convert all dataframe column value to ISO-8601 format**

*Given below the sample value I get, when I execute `print(df['timestamp'])` for reference*

0 2020-02-03 18:00:33 
1 2020-02-03 18:00:37 
2 2020-02-03 18:00:39 
3 2020-02-03 18:01:16 
4 2020-02-03 18:01:17 
5 2020-02-03 18:02:14 
6 2020-02-03 18:02:46 
7 2020-02-03 18:02:50 
8 2020-02-03 18:02:58

*Given below the* **Expected Result**

0 2020-02-03T18:00:33-06 
1 2020-02-03T18:00:37-06 
2 2020-02-03T18:00:39-06 
3 2020-02-03T18:01:16-06 
4 2020-02-03T18:01:17-06 
5 2020-02-03T18:02:14-06 
6 2020-02-03T18:02:46-06 
7 2020-02-03T18:02:50-06 
8 2020-02-03T18:02:58-06

Comment: What have you tried, show us some of your code! Also, it would help if you made your question a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks cole for the feedback, I will definitely add some minimal reproducible example while adding any questions in the future

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['timestamp'] = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=10, freq='H')
```

If you just want to output in isoformat:

```
df['timestamp'].map(lambda x: x.isoformat())
```

If you want to create an extra column:

```
df['iso_timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].map(lambda x: x.isoformat())
```

If you want to overwrite:

```
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].map(lambda x: x.isoformat())
```